# Uploading to EC2 problems. How do you do FTP?

Tags: ftp, ssh, amazon-ec2, sftp

I have setup a new EC2 instance on AWS and I'm trying to get FTP working to upload my application. I have installed VSFTPD as standard, so I haven't changed anything in the config file (/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf).

I have not set my port 21 in the security group, because I'm doing it through SSH. I log into my EC2 through termal like so

`sudo ssh -L 21:localhost:21 -vi my-key-pair ec2-user@ec2-instance`

I open up filezilla and log into local host. Everything goes fine until it comes to listing the directory structure. I can log in and right and everything seems fine as you can see below:

`Status: Resolving address of localhost

Status: Connecting to [::1]:21...

Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...

Response:   220 Welcome to EC2 FTP service.

Command:    USER anonymous

Response:   331 Please specify the password.

Command:    PASS ******

Response:   230 Login successful.

Command:    OPTS UTF8 ON

Response:   200 Always in UTF8 mode.

Status: Connected

Status: Retrieving directory listing...

Command:    PWD

Response:   257 "/"

Command:    TYPE I

Response:   200 Switching to Binary mode.

Command:    EPSV

Response:   229 Entering Extended Passive Mode (|||37302|).

Command:    LIST

Error:  Connection timed out

Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing`

Is there something which I'm missing in my config file. A setting which needs to be set or turned off. I thought it was great that it connected but when it timed out you could picture my face. It meant time to start trawling the net try and find the answer! Now with no luck.

I'm using the standard Amazon AMI 64 bit. I have a traditional lamp setup.

Can anyone steer me in the right direction? I have read a lot about getting this working but they are all incomplete, as if they got bored half way through typing up how to do it.

I would love to hear how you guys do it as well. If it makes life easier. How do you upload your apps to a EC2 instance? (Steps please - it saves a lot of time plus it is a great resource for others.)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I figured it out, after the direction help by Antti Haapala.

You don't even need VSFTP setup on the instance created. All you have to do is make sure the settings are right in FileZilla.

This is what I did (I'm on a mac so it should be similar on windows):

1. Open up file zilla and go to preferences.
2. Under preferences click sftp and add a new key. This is your key pair for your ec2 instance. You will have to convert it to the format FileZilla uses. It will give you a prompt for the conversion
3. Click okay and go back to site manager
4. In site manager enter in your EC2 public address, this can also be your elastic IP
5. Make sure the protocol is set to SFTP
6. Put in the user name of ec2-user
7. Remove everything from the password field - make it blank
8. All done! Now connect.

That's it you can now traverse your EC2 system. There is a catch. Because you are logged in as ec2-user and not root you will not be able to modify anything. To get around this, change the group ownership of the directory where your application will lie (/var/www/html) or what ever. I would change it so it is on a EBS volume. ;) Also make sure this group has read write and execute permissions. The group for the ec2-user is ec2-user. Leave everyone else as nothing. So the command you use while logged in via ssh

`sudo chgrp ec2-user file/folder

sudo chmod 770 file/folder`

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Well, you can always copy the public key from the ec2-user's .ssh/authorized_keys for the www-data, or whatever the user is called in your distribution... and connect directly as the www user.

Comment: After a full day of searching, this answer finally did it. Thanks so much for posting this!

Comment: This is the best answer on this page. And the most detailed. Digital high five!

Comment: Brilliant! This is seriously the most clear answer I've read **all day**. I wish people wrote answers like this all the time...

Comment: Awesome answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

FTP is a very troublesome protocol because it requires a secondary pipe for the actual data transfer and does not definitely work well when piped. With ssh you should use SFTP which has nothing to do with FTP but is a completely different protocol.

Read also on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol#Secure_FTP)

Comment: So I was going about it all wrong. I was trying to use FTP when I should of been doing SFTP. Thanks Antti Haapala!

Comment: No problem, lets kill the FTP :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding the key to www is a recipe for disaster! Any minor issue with your app will become a security nightmare.

As an alternative to ftp, consider using rsync or a more "mature" deploy strategy based on capistrano for instance. There are plenty of tools for that around.

Answer (score 0):

Antti Haapala's tips are the only way to work around with EC2 SFTP. It works just fine! Just note that you need to create the /var/www/.ssh/ folder and copy the authorized_keys file there.

After that you'll need to change authorized_keys ownership to www-data so ssh connection can recognize it. Amazon should let people know that. I looked for this in there forums, FAQ, etc. No clue at all... Cheers once more to stackoverflow, the way to go haha!